# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel

I have forums table, topics table and posts table. the relationship between the posts and topics to forums in one to many. I have implemented the relationship but when I try to access the topics count by doing `{{count($forum->topics)}}` I get this error: `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` However, when I try accessing the posts count in the same way:`{{count($forum->posts)}}`, it works correctly. Please help

Forum model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
    }

    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Topic');
    }
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
    }
}
```

Topic model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Topic extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function forum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Forum');
    }
}
```

Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public function forum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Forum');
    }
}
```

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: What does `$forum->topics->count()` shows?

Comment: ```public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::latest()->get();
        return view('welcome', \compact('categories'));
    }```  What happens is that, I have categories related tto forums and forums related to topics and posts. I send the categories to the view then loop through to display categories and forums under those categories then topics under those forums

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand ```Call to a member function count() on int``` It returns this error